# How to redirect an IP and port that is being listened to using iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables, port-forwarding, forwarding

I have a server with two external IPv4 addresses.  One address is essentially unused in that it doesn't appear in any DNS and I haven't employed it for anything.  I want to use port 80 on it now, but I am using a web server (lighttpd) on that machine which listens on 0.0.0.0:80 and which is difficult to make stop doing so without unpleasant consequences (either I lose having it listen on 127.0.0.1 or have to totally rewrite all its configs away from using any global settings).

Is there an easier way?  Can I forward port 80 on the "unused" IP somewhere else in a way that the stack will divert the packet before it gets to the listening lighttpd?  I would love to forward it over a VPN adapter on the same machine:

Server:

```
Public IP1 on eth0 = 55.66.77.8
Public IP2 on eth1 = 55.66.77.10
Wireguard IP on wg = 10.20.2.1

Lighttpd listening on 0.0.0.0:80
```

Can I forward eth1's `55.66.77.10:80` -> wg's `10.20.2.15:8080` out from under the Lighttpd listen?

I tried:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.20.2.15:8080
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 10.20.2.15 --dport 8080 -j SNAT --to-source 10.20.2.1
```

...which is working to forward other other ports on the same machine over the VPN.  In this case, though, `telnet 55.66.77.10 80` still reaches lighttpd, and isn't forwarded.

Comment: If your telnet is from localhost, then the interface is lo0, not eth1.  Is telnet from an *external* machine getting forwarded?

Answer (score 1):

lighttpd sockets inherit from the global scope, so if you have your config in the global scope, you can have

```
server.bind = "55.66.77.8"
$SERVER["socket"] == "127.0.0.1:80" { }
```

where you previously listened on `"*:80"`

If you're worried about modifying the existing config, you can add an include file at the end and can override some settings using `:=`, e.g.
`server.bind := "55.66.77.8"`

---

An alternative solution to iptables is to have lighttpd act as a reverse proxy to your 10.20.2.15:8080, using [lighttpd mod_proxy](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/mod_proxy).  lighttpd can perform the TLS termination, too, if listening on port 443.